# Rollback from ADFS to Windows Claims?

Tags: adfs, claims, windows, sharepoint-server

So, a time ago I implemented ADFS to my Sharepoint 2016 env. I migrated all the users to ADFS claims successfully with the help och this script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Migrate-users-ea83de43

The users looks like this: i:05.t|ADFS40|firstname.lastname@contoso.com

So, is there any way to migrate them back - to Windows Claims and keep their existing file/site permissions? I want to do a roll-back so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the Move-spuser command to loop through all the users and change their claim from i:05.t|ADFS40|firstname.lastname@contoso.com to the Windows Claim.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps